# Using logical Properties to prove a tautology

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

[image]

So I have to prove this as a tautology. I've been stuck on this forever and am not sure where to go. I experimented and got this far, and looking for some pointers on where to take it next.

(p → q) → ((p v r) → (q v r)) =

(~p v q) → (~(p v r) v (q v r)) : conditional law

~(~p v q) v (~(p v r) v (q v r)) : conditonal law

(p ^ ~q) v (~(p v r) v (q v r)) : De Morgan's law

(p ^ ~q) v ((~p ^ ~r) v (q v r)) : De Morgan's law

this is where I'm stuck. I feel like I should work the distributive law in, but it's not in the correct format for it

Comment: @Prometheus I'm sorry I might be misunderstanding you. But in my textbook, and online it says P → Q is logically equivalent to ~P v q. Which is what I did?

Answer (score 2):

The first few steps might seem a bit mysterious as they were figured out with a Karnaugh map, but the trick here is to make every term include either $p$ or $\neg p$:
\begin{align*}
&(p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land \neg r) \lor q \lor r \\
&\equiv (p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land \neg r) \lor (\top \land q) \lor (\top \land r) \\
&\equiv (p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land \neg r) \lor ((p \lor \neg p) \land q) \lor ((p \lor \neg p) \land r) \\
&\equiv (p \land \neg q) \lor (\neg p \land \neg r) \lor [(p \land q) \lor (\neg p \land q)] \lor [(p \land r) \lor (\neg p \land r)] \\
&\equiv [(p \land q) \lor (p \land \neg q) \lor (p \land r)] \lor [(\neg p \land r) \lor (\neg p \land \neg r) \lor (\neg p \land q)] \\
&\equiv[ p \land (q \lor \neg q \lor r)] \lor [\neg p \land (r \lor \neg r \lor q)] \\
&\equiv[ p \land (\top \lor r)] \lor [\neg p \land (\top \lor q)] \\
&\equiv[ p \land \top] \lor [\neg p \land \top] \\
&\equiv p \lor \neg p \\
&\equiv \top
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

From $((\neg p\wedge \neg r)\vee (q\wedge r))$ use associative rule,commutative rule and negation rule to get $\neg p\wedge q$. Then what is left is $(p\wedge \neg q)\vee (\neg p\wedge q)$. You can simplify this to get the tautology.

Comment: How would I use the associative rule? The associative law is     (p v q) v r = p v (q v r) and (p ^ q) ^ r = p ^ (q ^ r). Neither of them are the correct format, are they?